# Declarative approach to deploy Helm chart by Argocd to multiple environments

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argocd

I’m using Argocd with helm charts. I have two environments: *uat*, *prod*.

As far as I understand, proper approach for helm is to have base folder with commons + per env folder.

So I have single branch with 3 folders:

```
base # for commons: Chart.yaml, templates, etc.
uat  # for uat values.yaml
prod # for prod values.yaml
```

In my helm chart I have following *Chart.yaml* (stored in base folder):

```
apiVersion: v1
appVersion: 1.0.11 
name: my-nice-app
version: 1.0.11
```

With every release I increase *appVersion* and *version* (*version* is used as image tag version in charts).

I use declarative approach to deploy helm chart (this is uat application resource, similar is for prod):

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: my-nice-app
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  project: default

  source:
    repoURL: some-url
    targetRevision: HEAD
    path: base

    helm:
      version: v3
      valueFiles:
        - uat/values.yaml

  destination:
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
    namespace: uat

  syncPolicy:
    syncOptions:
    - CreateNamespace=false

    automated:
      selfHeal: true
      prune: true
```

Question:

I do update uat values file.

I do update Chart.yaml with new version.

I would like to deploy uat only (but when I update base prod would also triggers).

Where or how should I store Chart.yaml? Should I change Argocd Application resource? Or only option is to duplicate charts per env?

I prefer also not to store any version related info in Argocd Application resource (so not to change it every time).

It would be nice not to apply kustomized.io.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split it into 2 charts (`base chart` and `value chart`)
`base chart` is `chart dependency` of value chart, like that if you update base chart, `value chart` won't be affected if you don't update chart dependency.

File `Chart.yaml` of `value-chart` will look like this.

```
apiVersion: v2
name: my-nice-app-prod
description: Chart for production

type: application

version: 0.0.1

appVersion: "1.0.0"

dependencies:
- name: my-nice-app-chart
  version: 0.1.9
```

Link references:
https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency/

Answer (score 1):

You should use the variants folder,
The base directory holds configuration which is common to all environments. It is not expected to change often. If you want to do changes to multiple environments at the same time, it is best to use the “variants” folder.
Please go through this doc
https://codefresh.io/blog/how-to-model-your-gitops-environments-and-promote-releases-between-them/

Answer (score 1):

This is perfect use case to use generators:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: my-nice-app
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  generators:
    - list:
        elements:
          - cluster: dev
            server: https://ip.xx.xx.xx
            targetRevision: v3
          - cluster: staging
            server: https://ip.xx.xx.xx
            targetRevision: v2
          - cluster: prod
            server: https://ip.xx.xx.xx
            targetRevision: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: 'my-nice-app-{{cluster}}'
    spec:
      project: my-nice-app-project
      source:
        repoURL: https://helm-chart-repo.com
        targetRevision: '{{targetRevision}}'
        chart: myhelmchart
          valueFiles:
          - values-{{cluster}}.yaml
      destination:
        server: '{{server}}'
      syncPolicy:
        automated:
          prune: false
          selfHeal: true
```